Can I specialize class template on constness of the type?
In other words: Can a class Foo pass this compile-time test?
void prove_the_point() {
    Foo foo1{};
    const Foo foo2{};
    static_assert(sizeof(foo1) != sizeof(foo2));
}

Why?
I have inherited a large data science project. To aid reasoning through the code I started to enforce const-correctness.
There are objects, pointers to objects which I mostly had to replaced with shared_ptr, vectors, and inevitably vectors of smart pointers.
Now you may see where it is going: enforcing const-correctness on a vector of shared_ptr is arguably impossible to do, because const does not propagate without changing semantics of the API (e.g. by exposing iterators instead of vectors of pointers).
In the comments to How can I propagate const when returning a std::vector<int*> from a const method?, @Voo suggested that reinterpret_cast cannot be used, as there is no guarantee that memory layout for T and const T is the same. ("I don't think there's any guarantee that the memory layout must be the same for a container for T and const T.") If it is truth, then it means that const propagation would never ever work, because types Foo and const Foo could in principle be completely unrelated.
It made me wonder if it is possible to prove it. I know already, that I can specialize methods on constness of the type, but can I specialize the whole class, so I can have different data members for T and const T?

"as there is no guarantee that memory layout for T and const T is the same" Your link doesn't say that, I believe? It says that vector<T> and vector<const T> can be different, which isn't what you're saying.

Why tag both C++20 and C++26? What version are you using?

I don't see how the example given illustrates the question, it doesn't use any template. Did you mean Foo<T> vs Foo<const T>?

std::experimental::propagate_const might help.

This is not at all what you were asking, but your function is possible if Foo is a class template: https://godbolt.org/z/K7nExGcGq

@Artyer, very whichcrafty :O

@TedLyngmo my code base is compatible with C++20, but I am curious about the problem in principle, so I added the most recent version too.

@AdamRyczkowski C++23 isn't even released yet afaik and work on C++26 has just started. In order to narrow it down, it's usually best to stick with the version you are actually compiling with.

@AdamRyczkowski "I am curious about the problem in principle" -- This would suggest a lack of version tags, not a future version tag. The best fit for this site would probably be dropping both version tags and maybe mention in your question that you are interested in knowing when answers first applied. Or skip mentioning it. The C++ tag info says: "it is assumed that the current version is used. That is, whichever version of ISO/IEC 14882 ISO currently lists as active." That still lists C++20.

I updated your link to point to Voo's only comment on that question and included the relevant portion of that comment in your question (in case it gets deleted, and so that others can evaluate your paraphrasing). If you were referring to something else, please correct my update.

@Artyer It doesn't prove the point as Foo foo1; Foo foo2; also passes that test.

Allow me to modify your function slightly, by making foo2 a reference.
void prove_the_point() {
    Foo foo1{};
    const Foo& foo2 = foo1; // <-- Reference
    static_assert(sizeof(foo1) != sizeof(foo2));
}

This is legal, as non-const values can be bound to const references (and this can be done directly, no cast required). Rather than directly answering your question, I propose you look at this and ask yourself how things could go really, really bad if the sizes were not the same.
For a more thorough analysis, see the other answer.

OK, an answer should leave less to the reader. If sizeof(Foo) < sizeof(const Foo) then access through foo2 could read past the end of foo1, which would be undefined behavior, but reading foo2 is defined behavior. If sizeof(Foo) > sizeof(const Foo) then there is part of foo1 that cannot be accessed via foo2, which would break the reference semantics.

Thank you for showing me the reason why the sizes must match.

If sizeof(Foo) > sizeof(const Foo) then there is part of foo1 that cannot be accessed via foo2 -- isn't that perfectly ok? It's quite expected that accessing an object via const-reference is more restrictive. An object may have data members which are accessible only through non-const methods. And since non-const methods can't be legally called on a const object -- such data members might well be eliminated in a const object by an optimizing compiler. In fact, of course, they aren't eliminated, but for other reasons, not because "that cannot be accessed".

@IgorG "An object may have data members which are accessible only through non-const methods" -- This is true, but this cannot be determined from the class definition (excluding the definitions of member functions, since those definitions do not need to be inside the class definition). If a conclusion requires looking into the a source file, it cannot be made when compiling other source files. When compiling other source files, the compiler has no way to know if any data members are inaccessible via const-qualified member functions


Can I specialize class template on constness of the type?

No. const is not part of the template specialization.

Can a class Foo pass this compile-time test?

No. sizeof ignores const. const has no effect on the properties of the type.

enforcing const-correctness on a vector of shared_ptr is arguably impossible to do, because

There is the const property on the shared_ptr itself, which can be achieved by passing the std::vector<std::shared_ptr<T>> as std::span<const std::shared_ptr<T>>.
There is also the const property on the T, which is supposed to be independent of the const on the shared_ptr. Propagating shared_ptr with const throughout the vector is a bit more tricky, depending on what exactly you want to do. The question would be why you need to pass a std::vector<std::shared_ptr<T>> in such a way that access to the T elements will be const. Maybe passing a std::vector<const T*> constructed from the original vector is more appropriate if ownership isn't taken.

In the comments to How can I propagate const when returning a std::vector<int*> from a const method?, @Voo suggested that reinterpret_cast cannot be used, as there is no guarantee that memory layout for T and const T is the same. If it is truth, then it means that const propagation would never ever work, because types Foo and const Foo could in principle be completely unrelated.

That reinterpret_cast has undefined behavior has nothing at all to do with whether or not T and const T are related or have the same layout. reinterpret_casting between unrelated types is in almost all cases UB, regardless of layout. Layout does not determine at all whether such a cast is valid. Two types being specializations of the same template does not count as "related". Additionally, even if T and const T are exactly the same in every way, there is no guarantee that std::vector<const T> and std::vector<T> have the same layout and properties.

You're right in saying const doesn't change the memory layout of the T, which is what sizeof measures. But this doesn't mean that const has no effect on the properties T ; it still affects how the T can be used

@AbhishekShivakumar Kind of depends on to interpret "properties of the type". The point is that, except for being a T being a distinct type from const T, both as types share all properties. The only difference is that an object of the latter type has restrictions placed on it with regards to modification and that an expression of const type behaves differently in overload resolution and in which built-in expressions can be used with it.


Can a class Foo pass this compile-time test?

No.

Why?

Because standard qualification conversion is allowed on arrays. See:
Foo         arr[5];    // Array of 5 non-const Foo objects.

const Foo*  cp = arr;  // Pointer to a const Foo object.

cp[2];                 // Must access the third non-const element
                       // through the const pointer.

Which implies that sizeof(const Foo) used by pointer arithmetic when evaluating (cp+2) must be the same as sizeof(Foo) used in array memory layout.

Fundamentally In C++, const is a qualifier that prevents modification of an object. However, const typically doesn't change the memory layout of the object itself; it simply does what any type checker would do restricts how you can interact with the object.
Obviously, However in the case of sizeof(T) for a given type T  (like Foo) arguably is the same as sizeof(const T) simply because the const qualifier affects the type's mutability, not its size or memory layout.
If you check at complile time with say static_assert:
static_assert(sizeof(foo1) != sizeof(foo2)); 

This would fail to compile because the sizes are the same. sizeof(Foo) is equal to sizeof(const Foo) in almost all cases i.e.
For example
template <typename T>
class FooBase {
    // Common implementation for both const and non-const Foo
};

// Specialization for const T
template <>
class FooBase<const int> {
    int const_member;
};

// Specialization for non-const T
template <>
class FooBase<int> {
    int non_const_member;
};

class Foo : public FooBase<int> {};

class ConstFoo : public FooBase<const int> {};

void prove_the_point() {
    Foo foo1{};
    const Foo foo2{};
    static_assert(sizeof(foo1) != sizeof(foo2));
}

This code will throw beautiful errors simple because the memory layout is still the same in C++ because const never changes the actual size or structure of the object; it only changes how you can interact with the object.
